# Show that $f: (0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $ f(x) = \sin{\frac{1}{x}} $ is Lebesgue-integrable and calculate its Lebesgue Integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Show that the function $f: (0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $$ f(x) = \sin{\frac{1}{x}} $$ is Lebesgue-integrable and calculate its Lebesgue Integral.

Here my attempt:

$f$ is continuous in the domain so is Riemann-integrable. 
but how to calculate $$ \int \sin{\frac{1}{x}}? $$

It seems there is no elementary function for its anti-derivative.

So, how can I obtain $$ \int_{(0,1]} \sin{\frac{1}{x}}? $$

Comment: Maybe try a substitution such as $u={1 \over t}$. (See Daniel's answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/720076/27978.)

Comment: I already try that and get some strange integral $Ci(x) = \int{\frac{\cos x}{x}}$

Comment: I have not worked through the details, but Daniel's answer is likely correct.