# Prove that the function $g(x)=\begin{cases} \sin (\frac 1x)& x \neq 0 \\ 1& x=0 \end{cases}$ has no antiderivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, mean-value-theorem

> Prove that the function $$g(x)=\begin{cases}
>     \sin (\frac 1x) & x \neq 0 \\ 1 & x=0
> \end{cases}$$ is not a derivative of any function that is differentiable along the whole line.

We want to prove that $g$ has no antiderivative. Assume the opposite - let $g$ have an antiderivative $G$. Every antiderivative has the Darboux property, so for any $a,b$ in the domain of $G$, if $G(a)G(b)<0$, then there is $c\in (a,b)$ that $G(c)=0$.

I further tried to use mean value theorem to contradict the Darboux property assumption, but I didn't get anything meaningful. Could you please help me?

Comment: What would be more useful to you is Darboux's theorem stating that $g$ would have the Darboux property if it had an antiderivative. ([Wikipedia page for the theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This $g$ obeys the intermediate value (Darboux) property. To see this, note that it is continuous everywhere except at $x = 0$, but in any interval around $0$, no matter how small, it attains all values in $[-1, 1]$ and no other values (exercise: explain why this implies $g$ has the Darboux property).

Your idea to start with an antiderivative $G$ is a good one. Note that we can explicitly define what the antiderivative is at all points $x \neq 0$: $G(x) = \int_{0}^{x}\sin(1/t)dt$. This follows by the fundamental theorem of calculus, since $g$ is continuous for $x \neq 0$. This means that, for all $x \neq 0$, we have that $G'(x) = g(x)$, and further, we know that any antiderivative will equal (some translation of) $G$ for all $x \neq 0$. This means that, if $G$ fails to be an antiderivative for $g$, the failure needs to happen at $x = 0$.

What does it mean for $G$ not to be an antiderivative of $g$ at $x = 0$? It means precisely that $G'(0) \neq g(0)$. You have an integral expression for $G(x)$, which means you can compute $G'(0)$, and if you can show that it's distinct from $g(0)$, you're done. To that end, [The antiderivative of $\sin(1/x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720051/the-antiderivative-of-sin1-x) shows that $G'(0) = 0$, and so $g$ admits no antiderivative.